# Verify_password() : password not matching hash

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I apologize if this is too much of a newbie issue but I've been stuck with the password_verify function for days now. The problem would seem to be that the password entered in the login does not match the password in the database. Yet the passwords do match and I don't understand what the problem is! The passwords are stocked as VARCHAR 255 and when I use var dump on the two variables this is what I get:

string(60) "$2y$10$vfTK8JhbTjtwN3R2qED59uT1gvlD7XbczeacC7IMGn4kKi/1ETiP2" string(12) "Password123."

The problem does not solve if i switch place to $password, $row["password"] in password_verify

Does anyone know what the problem could be?
Thanks in advance

This is how I am trying to compare the password from the login with the one in the db.

```
<form method="post" > 
    <input class="input" type= "text" name="nom" placeholder="nom" required > <br>
     <input class="input" type= "password" name="password" placeholder="password" required><br>
    
    <input class="button" type= "submit" value="Login" name= "Submit1"> 
    <?php
//appel a la connexion de bdd
require_once ('conn.php');

///$_Post variables
$email = $_POST['nom'];
$password =  $_POST ['password'];

//Query
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE nom = :email");
$q->bindParam(':email', $email);
$q->execute(); // eseguo la query
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$rows = $q->rowCount();

if ($rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $q->fetch()) {
        var_dump($row["password"]);
        var_dump($password);

        //Password control
        if ((password_verify( $password, $row["password"]))) {
            echo 'right';
           
        }
       else {
        echo 'wrong';
       
    }
       
    }
}
```

This is how i store them in the first place

```
 <?php
//connessione bd
include 'conn.php';
include 'forminsertuser.php';


//recupero

if(!empty ($_POST["Submit1"])) 

{ 
    $password_hash= password_hash($arr['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$arr['nom'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['nom']);
$arr['password']= htmlspecialchars( $_POST ['password']);
$arr['rankid']=  $_POST ['rankid'];


$sql = 'INSERT INTO users ( nom, password, rankid) VALUES( :nom, :password, :rankid)';

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute([
':nom' => $arr['nom'],
    ':password' => $password_hash,
    ':rankid' => $arr['rankid'],
]);

 header("Location: process.php");
exit;
};
?>
```

Comment: you need to has the passwords https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: What is `$arr`? Should be hashing `$_POST ['password']`, no?

Comment: Hi nbk, I tought the password were hashed correctly? In my database i get a 60 charachter string and not the password i submitted

Comment: When you store the password, you're hashing `$arr['password']` before you have set the value of `$arr['password']`. So it's probably hashing NULL, isn't it? This should result in a bunch of warnings.

Comment: The hash you've posted is a hash of an empty string - see https://3v4l.org/V8gGc. As @BillKarwin said, you're calling `password_hash` with a variable that hasn't been set yet. Turn on PHP error reporting and you'll catch this kind of thing much quicker, certainly before you spend days on it.

Comment: You're also calling `htmlspecialchars()` at storage, but not when you check. This will cause problems for users that have special characters in their names or passwords. Seeing as your query is properly prepared you should not be calling that function there at all, but rather on _output_ when you need to ensure that it is safe for inclusion in an HTML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your password_hash variable is set in the wrong place.  It is using $arr before it has been initialized.

```php
<?php
//connessione bd
include 'conn.php';
include 'forminsertuser.php';


//recupero

if(!empty ($_POST["Submit1"])) 

{ 

$arr['nom'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST ['nom']);
$arr['password']= htmlspecialchars( $_POST ['password']);
$arr['rankid']=  $_POST ['rankid'];

// shifted here
$password_hash= password_hash($arr['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$sql = 'INSERT INTO users ( nom, password, rankid) VALUES( :nom, :password, :rankid)';

$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);

$statement->execute([
':nom' => $arr['nom'],
    ':password' => $password_hash,
    ':rankid' => $arr['rankid'],
]);

 header("Location: process.php");
exit;
};
?>
```